# Group previously-selected master questions in duplicate questions dialog

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, duplicate-questions, usability

When closing a post as an exact duplicate, there is a prompt to enter the question it is a duplicate of.  If there have been other votes to close as a duplicate, you will see the posts those other users thought it was an exact duplicate of.

The problem, as seen in this screenshot, is that the same master question gets listed multiple times.  They should be grouped and sorted by frequency cited, with something like "(3)" after them.

[image]

Comment: Grouped **and** sorted by frequency cited.

Comment: @pesto good point, i'll add that