# Duplicate question closing window shows the master question candidate many times

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Group previously-selected master questions in duplicate questions dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8604/group-previously-selected-master-questions-in-duplicate-questions-dialog)

The same question is shown just as many times as people have chosen it. I suggest putting the standard (X) where X is the number of people having selected it instead of repeating it.

[image]

Comment: Definitely makes sense.