# Ease selection of the master question in the duplicate question closing window

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

The current manner of selecting the candidate among the list is to retype the title or go see the candidate's id and type it.

Why not just click to select it? I don't suggest removing the link, which is useful to go read the candidates, but I do suggest adding some clickable control to select one automatically. This would be a nice addition.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This has been implemented ... uh... some time ago. :)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's so you don't get lazy and you actually go verify that the other question is indeed a duplicate. It's social engineering to avoid group thought.

Consider yourself manipulated.

Comment: Bah, people are doing the site a service and people in charge on purpose won't make it easier for you because you are presumed not to be responsible enough? Gimme a break. If you are not responsible enough you just won't even care about closing.

Comment: And by the way, you can just type the name of the question on the box (or look at the id on the link) without clicking on it. So I don't even buy that as a potential explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Though my mockup is a bit old (still has the all-red design) I, too, would like to see this screen updated so that people can select multiple questions to close by. This is especially important for moderators so that we can select multiple questions as the parent question. Several times I've taken to closing as a duplicate of one question, then editing the post to add links to other dupes. I think this can (and should) be taken care of through the interface directly:

[image: mockup]

Comment: I was actually thinking of selecting just one, but indeed selecting many makes sense to group them all, because there are indeed lots of threes and fours and sevens around

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to see the master question list grouped by question id. If there are two instances of question #n, then show that question followed by "x 2".

This will help with some true duplicates that have the same, or almost the same, title, but which are different questions.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11539/duplicate-question-closing-window-shows-the-master-question-candidate-twice

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice that question.

Answer (score 0):

As a moderator I would really like this to be modifief!

And wait till you have to clean up Superuser before calling someone lazy ;-)